# printing expressions of polymorphic type in ocamldebug

Tags: ocaml

Let's say we have a polymorphic function we'd like to debug, for example:

```
let rec rev lst = match lst with
  | [] -> []
  | x::xs -> List.append (rev xs) [x]
```

To make a program out of it, we add a main function:

```
let () = ignore (rev [1;2;3;4])
```

The result is irrelevant, but note rev is called with an int list i.e. a non-polymorphic type.

Still when I debug the execution in ocamldebug, I only get a generic list when i print the list argument:

```
(ocd) break @ Rev 1
(ocd) run
Breakpoint: 1
1 let rec rev lst = <|b|>match lst with
(ocd) print lst
lst: 'a list = [<poly>; <poly>; <poly>; <poly>]
```

I know there is no pure (i.e. non camlp4) way to have a generic print function, but does this restriction also hold for ocamldebug? In other words: Is it possible to obtain the list `[1;2;3;4]` instead of the `<poly>`s in the debugger?

**edit:**
User ivg proposed to install a printing function of the appropriate type via `#install_printer`. I created a new module pp with the following functions:

```
let rec pplist ch fmt = function
| [] -> ()
| x::xs -> 
   Format.fprintf ch "%s; " (fmt x); 
   pplist ch fmt xs

let int_list ch = pplist ch string_of_int
```

The toplevel reports the type correctly as `Format.formatter -> int list -> unit`. The ocamldebug session now looks as follows:

```
(ocd) load_printer pp.cmo
File ./pp.cmo loaded
(ocd)  install_printer Pp.int_list
(ocd)  break @ Rev 1
Loading program... done.
Breakpoint 1 at 14768 : file rev.ml, line 1, characters 19-84
(ocd) 
(ocd) run
Time : 12 - pc : 14768 - module Rev
Breakpoint : 1
1 let rec rev lst = <|b|>match lst with
(ocd) print lst
lst : 'a list = [<poly>; <poly>; <poly>; <poly>]
```

But it seems that ocamldebug does not use `int_list` and needs a polymorphic `'a list`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can install user printers the same way, as you do this in a toplevel. The command in named `install_printer` and is described in the [Manual](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/debugger.html). For example, if your element type is abstract, but provides a `to_string` function, you can write the printer for it:

```
let pp ch x = Format.fprintf ch "%s" (to_string x)
```

And then install the printer with the above mentioned directive.

### Update

The above will only you to print concrete types. Abstract values cannot be print. The only way is to restrict them (temporary) to concrete type:

Given a constraint program:

```
let rec rev lst : int list = match lst with
  | [] -> []
  | x::xs -> List.append (rev xs) [x]
```

The ocd will print the list:

```
Loading program... done.
Breakpoint 1 at 21448: file test.ml, line 1, characters 30-95
(ocd) run
Time: 12 - pc: 21448 - module Test
Breakpoint: 1
1 let rec rev lst : int list = <|b|>match lst with
(ocd) p lst 
lst: int list = [1; 2; 3]
```

The trick with installing a printer will save you from abstract types, not polymorphic.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer - somehow, ocamldebug does not use the custom print function. Should I create a new question or would you like to answer to this one? Anyways, I updated the question.

Comment: Thanks for the additional explanation - it's what i ended up doing, but it's a but annoying when the general code is really used with different types.